# Keeping track of removed elements using std::remove_if

Tags: c++, stl

I want to remove some elements from a `vector` and am using `remove_if` algorithm to do this. But I want to keep track of the removed elements so that I can perform some operation on them later. I tried this with the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct IsEven
{
    bool operator()(int n) 
    {
        if(n % 2 == 0)
        {
            evens.push_back(n);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    vector<int> evens;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(i);
    }

    IsEven f;
    vector<int>::iterator newEnd = remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), f);
    for(vector<int>::iterator it = f.evens.begin(); it != f.evens.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout<<*it<<"\n";
    }

    v.erase(newEnd, v.end());

    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't work as `remove_if` accepts the *copy* of my functor object, so the the stored `evens` vector is not accessible. What is the correct way of achieving this?

P.S. : The example, with even and odds is just for example sake, my real code is somethinf different. So don't suggest a way to identify even or odds differently.

Comment: You could pass your functor by reference. Is a solution acceptable using `boost` or `c++11` (for pass with `ref`)?

Comment: You can do the following `for(vector<int>::iterator it = newEnd; it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout<<*it<<"\n";
    }

    v.erase(newEnd, v.end());` to get correct results without involving `evens`

Comment: @megabyte1024: No that doesn't work. The elements beyond `newEnd` are not guaranteed to be the removed elements.

Comment: @megabyte1024: No, you can't (but see my answer). The range `[newEnd, end)` contains unspecified values; `remove_if `typically _copies_ matching elements; it doesn't swap them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is not `remove_if`, but it's cousin <strike>partial_sort</strike> `partition`. The difference is that `remove_if` only guarantees that `[begin, middle)` contains the matching elements, but `partition` also guarantees that `[middle, end)` contains the elements which didn't match the predicate.

So, your example becomes just (note that `evens` is no longer needed):

```
vector<int>::iterator newEnd = partition(v.begin(), v.end(), f);
for(vector<int>::iterator it = newEnd; it != v.end(); ++it)
{
    cout<<*it<<"\n";
}
v.erase(newEnd, v.end());
```

Comment: Does `partial_sort` return anything? This is not compiling on my system.

Comment: Eh, how did I pull that off? Fixing... Cross-eyed reading I think.

Comment: Thanks..I didn't know this..I just reversed my predicate condition and its working well now..

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is `std::partition()` which will rearrange all elts in the sequence such as all elts for which your predicate return `true` will precede those for which it returns false.

Exemple:

```
vector<int>::iterator bound = partition (v.begin(), v.end(), IsEven);
std::cout << "Even numbers:" << std::endl;
for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != bound; ++it)
  std::cout << *it << " ";

std::cout << "Odd numbers:" << std::endl;
for (vector<int>::iterator it = bound; it != v.end(); ++it)
  std::cout << *it << " ";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid copying your functor (i.e. pass by value) if you pass ist by **reference** like this:

```
vector<int>::iterator newEnd = remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
   boost::bind<int>(boost::ref(f), _1));
```

If you can't use `boost`, the same is possible with `std::ref`. I tested the code above and it works as expected.

Comment: +1, but please note, that `boost::ref` is predecessor of `std::ref`. It was first introduced in boost, than made it to TR1 (so many compilers have it as `std::tr1::ref` and was finally standardized in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

An additional level of indirection.  Declare the vector locally, and
have `IsEven` contain a copy to it.  It's also possible for `IsEven` to
own the vector, provided that it is dynamically allocated and managed by
a `shared_ptr`.  In practice, I've generally found the local variable
plus pointer solution more convenient.  Something like:

```
class IsEven
{
    std::vector<int>* myEliminated;
public:
    IsEven( std::vector<int>* eliminated = NULL )
        : myEliminated( eliminated )
    {
    }
    bool
    operator()( int n ) const
    {
        bool results = n % 2 == 0;
        if ( results && myEliminated != NULL ) {
            myEliminated->push_back( n );
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Note that this also allows the `operator()()` function to be `const`.  I
think this is formally required (although I'm not sure).

Comment: I would give it +1 if it was using reference and not pointer. And I'd probably leave it at plain-old-data and initialize local variable with initializer, when I have to create one for the vector anyway.

Comment: @JanHudec It's undefined behavior if it uses a reference; functional objects must be CopyAssignable.  And leaving it POD means that you can't construct a temporary: my use pattern would be to declare the vector, then use `IsEven( &v )` as the argument for the `remove_if`.

Comment: Hm, I can't find definite statement that it has to be Assignable and not just CopyConstructible, so I am kind of confused now. Reference obviously is CopyConstructible, but not Assignable.

Comment: @JanHudec I can't find a statement that it has to be either in C++03 (but maybe I haven't looked in the right places).  Still, since they're passed by value, value semantics seem to be indicated, and value semantics means both copy and assignment.  (At any rate, I wouldn't make something publicly copy constructable without also making it assignable.)

Comment: I've kind of grown the habit of making everything reference and if it turns out not to work, e.g. because it needs to be assignable in addition to copyable, I curse and change it. It's because pointers are [evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/big-picture.html#faq-6.15) (less things can happen to reference than pointer, so you don't have to take as many things into account when reading code using references as you have to when reading code using pointers).

Comment: @JanHudec Less things can happen with a reference.  I agree.  In particular, you can't assign if you have a reference.  I tend to avoid references everywhere but as function parameters, and return values in the few special cases where you want to grant access to the internals, and can be sure that the function can't fail to find the appropriate part of the internal.  I tend to avoid references in classes, even when they wouldn't cause a problem.  Do you use a reference in pimpl idiom?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see with the code is that the `evens` vector that you create inside the struct gets created everytime the remove_if algorithm calls it. So no matter if you pass in a functor to remove_if it will create a new vector each time. So once the last element is removed and when the function call ends and comes out of the function the f.evens will always fetch an empty vector. This could be sorted in two ways,

1. Replace the struct with a class and declare evens as static (if that is what you wanted)
2. Or you could make evens global. I wouldn't personally recommend that( it makes the code bad, say no to globals unless you really need them).

Edit:

As suggested by nabulke you could also std::ref something likke this, std::ref(f). This prevents you from making the vector global and avoids for unnecessary statics.

A sample of making it global is as follows,

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
vector<int> evens;

struct IsEven
{
    bool operator()(int n) 
    {
        if(n % 2 == 0)
        {
            evens.push_back(n);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(i);
    }

    IsEven f;
    vector<int>::iterator newEnd = remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), f);
    for(vector<int>::iterator it = evens.begin(); it != evens.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout<<*it<<"\n";
    }

    v.erase(newEnd, v.end());

    return 0;
}
```

This code seems to work just fine for me. Let me know if this is not what you wanted.

Comment: Wouldn't passing the functor with `std::ref` help?

Comment: @nabulke: Hhhhmmm I guess so. That could add to the possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may have another solution; only if you don't need to remove elts in the same time (do you?). With `std::for_each()` which returns a copy of your functor. Exemple:

```
IsEven result = std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), IsEven());

// Display the even numbers.
std::copy(result.evens.begin(), result.evens.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int> (cout, "\n"));
```

Take note that it is always better to create unnamed variables in c++ when possible. Here that solution does not exactly answer your primary issue (removing elts from the source container), but it reminds everyone that std::for_each() returns a copy of your functor. :-)